# Using Spring ReflectionUtils

Tags: java, spring

I don't **fully** understand the **last line** in following piece of code

```
 Field init = ReflectionUtils.findField(ABCClass.class, "init");
 ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(init);
 init.set(null, false);
```

What i do understand that its setting the AbcClass.init=false using Reflection API. What i dont understand is why we dont have a setter like

```
set(Object value) // looks logical as we have reference to field , we can simply set the value
```

but instead we have Something like

```
set(Object obj,Object value)
```

I went through the api doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)
it says

> If the underlying field is static, the obj argument is ignored; it may
>   be null.
>
> Otherwise the underlying field is an instance field. If the specified
>   object argument is null, the method throws a NullPointerException.

But in my test case its not throwing any null pointer exception

I tried googling around for more example usage of this api , didnt find any useful example , may be some more examples can help me understand better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`init` is a static method on ABCClass. As the documentation says, if the underlying field is static, the first argument is ignored; it may be null.

Answer (score 1):

The reason I can imagine is this.

The way you are getting that field it doesn't know the instance it belongs to. In static fields that is fine since static makes the field belong to the class and can exist independently without an instantiated object.

But a non static field will need an instantiated object to exist. Resulting in the set method requiring to know what that instance is.

Comment: can you point me to some example code , will help me understand further